Why can't a vehicle (in a vacuum) propel itself by accelerating and decelerating a rotating mass?
I understand that a vehicle cannot change velocity by accelerating a mass from the front to the back, as it will need to decelerate the mass (and return it to the front), which cancels out any change in velocity.
I'm struggling to understand why it cannot instead accelerate a rotating mass from the front to the back, then decelerate the mass back down to its initial speed, as it rotates (under its own momentum) from the back to the front.
In the following diagram, blue is forwards and pink is backwards:

In practice, you'd pair counter-rotating masses to cancel out torque and vibration. There are a few different ways to configure things, but the following is the easiest to illustrate (though it'd be more fun to stack the disks, and build a UFO):

Accelerating the mass as it rotates backwards would propel the ship forward. Likewise, decelerating the mass as it rotates forward (under its own angular momentum) would also propel the ship forward.
While that makes sense, this would allow the ship to propel itself through space without losing mass (contradicting Newton), so I am obviously missing something.

Note: The rotation is not the important part (it does nothing by itself). However, the rotation allows the mass to be accelerated all the way to the back, and decelerated all the way to the front. This is unlike a straight rail, where the mass can only accelerate half of the way, then has to slow down, stop, and then repeat the process in reverse to get back to where it started. Rotating a mass at a constant speed is analogous to the rail. You also get a wobble, left to right, but that's incidental. Ultimately, everything cancels out in a simple, intuitive way.

The question is why the ship does not accelerate forward, despite pushing against masses the entire time. What am I not getting?

Well, angular momentum is angular and conserved. You cannot generate a linear momentum from changes of an angular momentum.

I know, but I asked why. Which part of what I wrote is wrong? Does the ship decelerate at some point? If so, when?

There is a fundamental theorem that relates symmetries of systems to conserved quantities. Linear momentum is associated with translational invariance whereas angular momentum relates to rotational invariance. This is the fundamental reason that we cannot generate a net of one momentum from the other. I recommend reading about the Noether theorem - it is one of the most fundamental concepts of our view of the universe. On a side note: it was proven by German-Jewish Mathematician Emmy Noether which, according to eg. Einstein, was the most influential and important female Mathematician.

Even if it is possible to gain momentum forwards by pushing the ball to rotate and then by being pushed by the ball on its way back in the circle, then wouldn't you have to being the ball along with you? Any gained speed of the vehicle must then be supplied to the ball as well, otherwise it would not be possible to keep this up - and then this just corresponds to pushing off from an external object.

The 'ball' is attached to the ship, via a rotating arm or disk. The animation is relative to the ship. You can always accelerate the ball backwards (relative to the ship), and then must decelerate it as it swings forward, so RPM remains constant over time (just like the animation).

Your "player bouncing a ball" system excludes the Earth. In order to make a ball with mass 6 kg change its velocity by 1 m/s at the bounce, the Earth's velocity must change by $10^{-24},\rm m/s$; otherwise momentum is not conserved. This movement of the Earth is small enough that we frequently neglect it without problems. In practice, momentum is conserved via non-negligible local deformations of the non-rigid Earth, such as deformations of the floor which then propagate through the Earth as sound waves.

Cool. But we're using rotation to return the mass to its initial position, so don't need the Earth to bounce off.

I just like the basketball analogy, because it brings to mind a hand pushing the ball down, then slowing the ball as it rises. The hand is being pushed in the same direction in both cases, which is basically what I'm trying to describe, just using a rotating ball.

I think you are also neglecting the center-pointing forces required to maintain circular motion. Would your idea work if the back-and-forth mass moved along a straight line, like a yo-yo or a mass on a spring?

I've figured it out. I'll leave an answer. Thanks. Your questions helped a lot.

Thanks again, @rob. It was "the center-pointing forces" that I was ignoring.

EDIT: I have had to change my original answer as it did not take into account the varying rotation speed.
@CarlYounger I have now come to the conclusion that your self-answer is correct. Your device is mechanically the same as the Sandy Kidd Gyroscopic Inertial Thruster, but his drive accelerates the counterweights towards the front and decelerates the counterweights towards the back. Sandy proposed the greater rotation speed of his weights while they were at the front would result in a thrust in the forward direction due to the greater centrifugal force during the fast half of the cycle. Let's call this thrust that Sandy Kidd has identified the "SK thrust".
Conversely, your drive decelerates the counterweights towards the front and accelerates the counterweights towards the back. You have correctly identified a thrust that results from the differential acceleration in the two halves of the cycle that I will call the "CY thrust".
The reason that the Sandy Kidd device does not work as intended is that the SK thrust is exactly opposed by the CY thrust, and the reason the Carl Younger device does not work is that the CY thrust is exactly opposed by the SK thrust. The two forms of thrust always cancel each other out no matter what algorithm is proposed for the varying acceleration and deacceleration of the rotating counterweights. The trusts cancel each other out over the course of a full rotation cycle, but not at any given instant, and this means there will always be vibration due to the rotation of the counterweights in either drive.
It is worth noting that the Wikipedia article does not offer an intuitive explanation for why the Sandy Kidd device does not work, and I believe your proposal and answer are a useful contribution in clarifying why either device cannot produce useable thrust.
The overriding governing principles are conservation of momentum and Newton's third law. Even when there is an internal power source, momentum has to be conserved at every instant. With a conventional rocket, the increase in momentum of the rocket due to burning fuel is matched by the opposite momentum of the expelled propellant. With the proposed reactionless drives, there is a supposed increase in the momentum of the vehicle with no corresponding propellant mass with the opposite momentum, violating the conservation of momentum principle and Newton's third law (but you knew that already).

Don't worry, it is actually me apologizing to you for interrupting your edit. Thank you for your kindness :-)

I understood all of this already. I said so in the question. This is just generally what happens when the masses rotate at a fixed rate. It doesn't address the specific issue I asked about.

@CarlYounger just added a bit to my answer that might help.

You said "the counterweights are accelerated back towards the front to complete the cycle". They are not accelerated towards the front. They swing toward the front (due to their angular momentum), and the ship decelerates them during that phase (by forcing the masses to push on the ship). That's the specific point that everyone keeps overlooking, and that's why it's so frustrating having this conversation.

I added a diagram and an animation to the question. They may help make the question clearer.

I always understood that the rotation (alone) doesn't change anything. It's the acceleration towards the back, and the deceleration towards the front, that seems like it would work. I'm trying to better understand physics, and was totally stumped by this problem.


As I understand it, accelerating the mass (as it rotates fore to aft) would increase the vehicle velocity. Likewise, decelerating the mass (as it rotates aft to fore under its own angular momentum) would also increase the vehicle velocity.

From your question and comments there seems to be a bit of confusion regarding "accelerating" and "decelerating", so I will not speak in those terms, but in terms of "accelerating forward" and "accelerating backward".
Accelerating the mass forward would decrease the vehicle velocity forward, and accelerating the mass backward would increase the vehicle velocity forward. The rotation of the mass is irrelevant.
To go into a little more depth. According to Newton’s 2nd law, accelerating the mass forwards requires a force in the forward direction
acting on the mass. According to Newton’s 3rd law, that forward force on the mass is equal and opposite the backward force on the vehicle. Again according to Newton’s 2nd law, this backward force on the vehicle produces a backward acceleration on the vehicle. The rotation doesn’t stop Newton’s laws

The mass will then naturally swing back round to its initial position

Addressing your edit, the mass will not naturally swing back. By Newton’s first law its center of mass will naturally continue in a straight line at constant velocity. The only way to alter that is to exert a force on it. That force comes from the vehicle, and Newton’s 3rd law applies as described above.

One deleted. Let's remain respectful about each other's abilities and intelligence.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I think I've figured it out. I'll reuse this animation to explain:

It is true that accelerating the mass as it rotates through the right half pushes the ship forward. It is also true that decelerating the mass as it rotates through the left half pushes the ship forward. However, the mass also pulls the ship backwards, via the disk (or arm) it's attached to, as the mass rotates through the bottom half.
While the mass will also pull the ship forwards when it rotates through the top half, the bottom half is the fast half, so the mass pulls back much more than it pulls forward.
The more aggressively we accelerate the mass (and push the ship forward), the greater the difference between the (stronger) force pulling back at the bottom and the (weaker) force pulling forward at the top. Ultimately, everything will always cancel out.

Your technique works if, and only if, the vehicle/rotor combination is subject to a varying external force.  I can think of two examples which are informing your intuition, but which do not apply to a properly isolated object.
Consider a very young person riding a rocking horse.  One mode is just to rock back and forth, like an inverted swing.  But one can also yank hard upwards on the handle, so that the rockers slide forward, then roll back towards the equilibrium position without sliding.  This technique takes advantage of the fact that static friction coefficients are necessarily larger than kinetic friction coefficients, so the force between the floor and the rockers depends on the horse's rate of rotation.  I fondly remember riding such a horse all over my house. (Exactly once, I rode it down a staircase.)
Or consider a swimmer, completely underwater, rotating their arms using exactly the method you describe.  Such a swimmer will be propelled forward because drag in a fluid goes like speed squared; there is more drag during the rapid motion than during the slower motion.  It is the environment which pushes the swimmer forward.
Internal interactions can change the mass distribution of an object, but can't change the momentum of the object's center of mass.

Thanks, Rob, but this just elaborates on my first paragraph, and doesn't answer the question: At what point does the ship lose the acceleration it gains by pushing the mass towards the rear, noting that the mass is pushing on the ship the rest of the time?

Take the perpetual motion perspective. If we use brakes to slow the rotating mass, all of the energy we put in to accelerate its rotation would be recovered or converted to heat when we decelerate its rotation, so we could not move without free energy. However, there are no brakes. We are decelerating the rotation by essentially putting the ship in the way of the mass, so the mass slows down by pushing on the ship. Now, there's energy in (from the ship) that can only leave the system by pushing the ship forward.

Are you imagining the experiment in a reference frame where the ship/rotor system is initially at rest?

Not specifically, no. The mass moves slowest as it passes the front, and fastest as it passes the back, but the exact speeds are not important. You could increase the difference between the lowest and highest speeds to accelerate faster (if it actually worked).

How does your analysis change if you do consider a reference frame where the ship/rotor system is initially at rest? You always have this freedom, and it simplifies the analysis.

As I understand it, It just accelerates forward. It always accelerates forward, because it is always pushing against a mass. I updated the answer (a third time) to try to be more specific about exactly what I'm asking (everyone keeps addressing a much more basic question - one that I don't have). Thing is, I do 3D graphics programming, and video game physics. I know enough linear algebra to get by. I never thought rotating the masses would make any difference by itself. I do appreciate that everyone is trying to help. I just want help with my actual problem.

Let's call the rotating mass a flywheel.
Say you rotate the flywheel by applying a backward force at the bottom edge. This will apply a forward force to your vehicle. However, if the flywheel rotates on an axle at its centre of mass, and the axle is attached to your vehicle (which it must be; otherwise you will lose the flywheel), then the axle will apply an equal and opposite (forward) force to the flywheel, resulting in an equal backward force on the vehicle.  So the vehicle will experience no forward or backward acceleration. Instead it will just rotate in the opposite direction to the flywheel.
Now, let's say the axle is not at the centre of mass of the flywheel - let's say's it's above the centre of mass. In this case, you could accelerate the centre of mass of the flywheel backwards, resulting in a forward acceleration of the vehicle. But as the centre of mass rotates, it experiences a centripetal force towards the axle, resulting in an equal and opposite rotating force on the vehicle. The result is a wobbling vehicle, with no sustained acceleration in any direction.

Yes. Correct. But in my example, we're only accelerating the flywheel as the off-center mass moves from the front to the back. We're actively decelerating the flywheel as its mass moves from the back to the front (and have a counter-rotating flywheel to offset torque and vibrations along the other axis). We're not just rotating a mass at a constant speed. It's the acceleration and deceleration that seems to impart linear velocity.

If you only accelerate the flywheel as the off-centre mass moves from front to back, then yes, you will get a forward acceleration of the vehicle. But it will only be temporary. As the off-centre mass rotates around the axle and starts moving upwards relative to the vehicle, it will apply a backwards force to the axle (and vehicle) that will take back all the forward momentum that the vehicle had. As it continues rotating and starts moving forwards, it will apply a backwards force to the vehicle.

Again, you're assuming the rate of rotation is constant. In that case, this would make perfect sense, but I acknowledged that in the first paragraph of my question.

In my scenario, we only input energy while the mass rotates from the front to the back (accelerating throughout that half-turn). Then, as the mass spins back around (from the back to the front) under its own momentum, we allow it to push on the ship, slowing the mass, and further accelerating the ship.
